# When should you let IIS auto-generate machine keys compared to using a static one?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I know very little about IIS but from what I've read there are lots of reason why you should generate a key and stick with that one. I haven't seen any reason to let it automatically generate one at runtime, though.

Aside from being marginally easier to setup, is there any good reason to leave it as-is?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to manually generate one is to configure forms authentication to work in a web farm, where each server in the farm needs the same key.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731979(v=ws.10).aspx